# How to prove Gibbs measure

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

There is a simple idea from 5th Landau volume. Let's assume that we have two independent systems A and B. We suppose they are in a thermostat with certain temperature and have energies $E_A$ and $E_B$ with probabilities $W(E_A)$ and $W(E_B)$.
The author of my lecture notes says that $A\oplus B$ system has energy $E_A+E_B$ with probability $W(E_A)W(E_B)$. But I don't understand why the probabilities must be multiplied because $E_A+E_B$ for ex. can also consist of energies $(E_A-1J)+(E_B+1J)$.

Comment: So I think $W(E_A+E_B)=\int_0^{E_A+E_B}W(E_A+E_B-E)W(E)dE$ or smth like that

Comment: One other thing to remember is that, if $A$ and $B$ are independent then P(A and B) = P(A)P(B). The independence of your systems A and B is related to the reason that the total probability is a product of individual probabilities.

Comment: The original argument was probably with $W$ being very large number of microstates for macroscopic system, not mathematical probability. The argument is that good estimate of number of microstates for the combined system, provided numbers for subsystems are $W_A$ and $W_B$, is $W_A . W_B$. This is because the number of microstates where energy distribution deviates from $E_A,E_B$ (e.g. by 1J as you suggest), is negligible.

Comment: thank you very much, I think you should post this as answer not a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Ján Lalinský said:
The original argument was probably with W being very large number of microstates for macroscopic system, not mathematical probability. The argument is that good estimate of number of microstates for the combined system, provided numbers for subsystems are WA and WB, is WA.WB. This is because the number of microstates where energy distribution deviates from EA,EB (e.g. by 1J as you suggest), is negligible. –

Answer (score 0):

The comment you added is correct. The product $W_A W_B$ is *not* the probability that the combined system has energy $E_A+E_B$ but rather the probability to catch the combined system with part $A$ at energy $E_A$ and part $B$ and energy $E_B$, which of course makes the total energy $E_A+E_B$.

As you correctly say in the comment, the probability to find the combined system at energy $E_A+E_B=E$ is
$$
   W(E)=\int_0^E W(E-E_B)\, W(E_B) dE_B
$$
which is what you have written in the comment.

Read your notes again and see that they say what you thing they do. Then ask the author of the notes for clarification. Imprecise language can cause huge problems with probabilities (and with thermodynamics).

Comment: @hft Of course. I edited the answer -- thanks for reporting.